# How do I delete config data with a button?

Tags: magento

So after the user saves config, let's say they now want to delete the config data. I think i should be running the delete method in the model but I am unsure how to attach it to a button. I tried having the button go to a controller action which uses getModel and runs its delete method then it redirects back to the config page but it didnt work and how can I set a success message so that it will show up after a redirect ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conventionally, Magento config data does not get removed from the database unless it is writeable at higher scope than the scope being deleted - ref [`Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Config_Data::save()`](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Config/Data.php#L195). It is more appropriate to treat an empty field as "value not set".

If fields are to be removed as part of a change in module version, it's possible to do this through [`Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::deleteConfigData()`](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php#L915).

Comment: I ended up using: `Mage_Core_Model_Config::saveConfig()`